# VBA Memory Usage: Declaring the same variable in diferrent subs vs publicly in module

Tags: vba, excel

Quick question about memory usage as I would like to always be writing my code optimally. I looked around but wasn't finding my question exactly.

I have several worksheets in my workbook that I usually create when I start a new excel/vba project. Those may be things like "LIBRARY" and "DATA". At the start of each sub I will declare:

```
Dim libWS as Worksheet
Dim dataWS as Worksheet
Set libWS = Worksheets("LIBARARY")
Set dataWS = Worksheets("DATA")
```

I do this for each sub that will utilize those worksheets. My question is, would it be more optimal or just the same to declare those worksheets publicly in the module and use a workbook open macro to initialize them.

Module 1:

```
public libWS as Worksheet
public dataWS as Worksheet
```

This Workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set libWS = Worksheets("LIBARARY")
    Set dataWS = Worksheets("DATA")
End Sub
```

Optimal meaning in terms of both speed/memory usage.

Thanks

Comment: I think question is better served in code review. Try posting your full code there for a good response.

Comment: I would not do that for at least couple of reasons: (1) global variables! (2) if an unhandled error ends up resetting your VB project, your globals are wiped and the rest of your code will them bomb out. Maybe instead create a single function which returns a "settings" object (with fields for each of your sheets) and call that whenever you need to work with commonly-accessed items.  Or change the codenames of your sheet objects in the VBProject then you can just refer to them as (eg) `libWS` without having to declare them or set them to anything.   Depending on how static your sheets are.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I didn't know there was a code review section. I'll utilize that in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both options are unnecessary as you can directly refer to the worksheets as objects in the Excel object model. If you rename the objects (not the worksheet names) to `DATA` and `LIBRARY`:

[image]

Then you can refer to them in code like this:

[image]

Comment: Robin, thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't know you could rename those objects and use them in the subroutine. This will make my life a lot easier!
A side questions that I was hoping to get out of this discussion was with regards to memory usage, and I don't think that question was quite answered. Perhaps you could help.. Given that I was declaring those worksheets with every sub "libWS as Worksheet / Set libWS = Worksheets("LIBRARY"), were those declarations eating up memory as if they were its own sheet? lets say I had those stated 5 times, would that be equal to having 5 added sheets?

Comment: A sheet variable is just a pointer to the object itself - it doesn't create a "copy" of the sheet

Comment: @Citanaf - per what Tim said your method would not used equivalent memory for an actual sheet just because you declared a variable for it. There would be some small amount of memory required for the variable itself and that it pointed to your worksheet object.

Comment: Hi Tim, Robin, thank you both. I was nervous that I was utilizing a ton of memory without necessity. Appreciate the clarity from both of you. Now I'm going back through my projects and removing some of these unnecessary declarations. Cheers!